# mockito on jdbcTemplate throwing compilation error

Tags: spring, mocking, mockito, junit4, jdbctemplate

I am trying to mock jdbcTemplate to throw an exception.

I am trying to throw exception on this method on JdbcTemplate

`<T> List<T> query(String sql, Object[] args, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)`

Here is what I have

```
@MockBean
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

Mockito.doThrow(exception).when(jdbcTemplate.query(anyString(), anyList(), any(MyMapper.class)));
```

I get compilation error, `cannot resolve method`. I also tried

```
Mockito.doThrow(exception).when(jdbcTemplate.query(anyString(), anyList(), Matchers.<RowMapper<MyMapper>>any()));
```

but still get same error.

what is the right way to do it here?

**EDIT**

As suggested in one of the answers, I tried

```
 Mockito.doThrow(exception).when(jdbcTemplate).query(anyString(), anyList(), any(MyMapper.class));
```

I still get `cannot resolve the method` error.

Answer (score 8):

The following calls will compile:

```
Mockito.doThrow(exception).when(jdbcTemplate).query(
    Mockito.anyString(), 
    Mockito.any(Object[].class), 
    Mockito.any(MyMapper.class)
);

Mockito.doThrow(exception).when(jdbcTemplate).query(
    Mockito.anyString(), 
    Mockito.any(Object[].class), 
    ArgumentMatchers.<RowMapper<MyMapper>>any())
);
```

The key difference between these and what you had tried previously is the second argument. In this method:

```
<T> List<T> query(String sql, Object[] args, RowMapper<T> rowMapper) throws DataAccessException;
```

... the second argument is:

```
Object[] args
```

It looks like you were matching this with `anyList()` which returns `List<T>`. Since this parameter is of type `Object[]` it should be matched with something which returns an `Object[]`. For example:

```
Mockito.any(Object[].class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Mockito.doThrow(exception).when(jdbcTemplate).query(anyString(), anyList(), any(MyMapper.class));
```

The `when()` call is to wrap your mock; you don't call your method within the `when()` call you do it after that wrapping to indicate to Mockito what you are expecting to happen to it.

Comment: Please provide some details as to why this would work.

Comment: This did not work either. I still get "cannot resolve method"

Comment: Have you debugged and ensured that your jdbcTempalte is indeed getting populated properly with a mock?

Comment: This: `doThrow(exception).when(mock).methodXXX(...)` **is** the correct form of call however it does not address the compilation error in this case.